# ¿Error al integrar aplicación web Struts2 y Spring + JPA + JNDI Universidad Java Udemy?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, struts2

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Estoy realizando un crud con Strut2 y Spring Framework y jpa  pero al ejecutar la aplicación me tira el siguiente error.

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: El nombre [persistence/PersistenceUnit] no este asociado a este contexto
```

Desearia que me pudiesen ayudar ya que no se a que se debe ese error.

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ejemplo.proyecto.capaservicio" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ejemplo.proyecto.capadatos" />
    
    <!-- Obtiene el entity manager inyectado en la fabrica de Spring -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" /> 
    
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />

    <!--Nombre que mapea con la Unidad de Persistencia en el archivo web.xml-->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence/PersistenceUnit" />
            
    <!-- Detecta @Transactional -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

Web.xml

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
    version="3.1">
    
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  
  <!-- Integracion con Struts Framework-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- integracion con Spring Framework-->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <!-- nombre utilizado en el archivo applicationContext.xml de Spring y JPA-->
     <persistence-unit-ref>
        <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence/PersistenceUnit</persistence-unit-ref-name>
        <persistence-unit-name>PersistenceUnit</persistence-unit-name>       
    </persistence-unit-ref>
</web-app>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
    <persistence-unit name="PersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/PersonaDb</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/> 
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Dejo el ejercicio de udemy del curso de Universidad Java para que vean donde me generan el error.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15gDRDmVdB52uQujlSV1waI0khufcibvI?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregar lo siguiente en tu context.xml, debajo (fuera) del **< context />**
¿o era dentro ? (prueba en ambos :v)

```
<Resource 
auth="Container" 
driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" 
maxActive="20" 
maxIdle="10" 
maxWait="-1" 
name="persistence/PersistenceUnit" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
url="jdbc:derby:flexeraDB;create=true" 
/>
```

Sí no te funciona intenta meterlo directamente en server.xml de tu Apache Tomcat ( suponiendo que estas usando este servidor).

Si deseas compartes tu repo git para ver que ocurre al instanciar tu BD.

Comment: no soluciono mi error. El ejemplo que he realizado es del curso de udemy universidad Java el tema de Struts2.

Comment: Te paso el link del proyecto : https://drive.google.com/file/d/136CPayFfTsjnL7GzmKufqch14gtdGn01/view?usp=sharing es de udemy. Universidad Java

Comment: La única diferencia es que yo lo estoy haciendo en eclipse y ello esta en netbeans